Insert INTO #TempTable is fast but SELECT * FROM #TempTable is very slow, why and how to improve performance?
I need to insert into temp table "#Temp" 300 000 rows and 30 columns from different tables, I created indexes and inserting is very fast, it needs about 3 seconds. But then, when I want to read from this temp table it takes very long - about 3 minutes, can I do something for speed up this process?
I tried to create indexes but it does not work at all, as I don't need to use ORDER BY with the final result.
Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?
SELECT 
    op.OperationId,
    op.OperationTypeId,
    op.BranchId,
    op.DateUpdated,
    op.OperationDate,
    op.StepCountTypeId,
    op.UserId,
    op.StatusTypeId,
    op.ChannelTypeId,
    cash.Amount, cash.OperationPersonId, cash.CurrencyTypeId
INTO #Operation
FROM CashDesk.Cash.Operation op
LEFT JOIN CashDesk.Cash.CashOperation AS cash WITH (NOLOCK) ON op.OperationId=cash.OperationId
WHERE CAST(op.OperationDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '2024-04-01' AND '2024-04-30'
AND op.OperationTypeId IN (9, 11, 10, 13, 14, 15, 348, 369, 385, 432)

SELECT * FROM #Operation


There are several reasons you should not be using NOLOCK

One improvement is the Cast(OperationDate As Date), because this must be computed for every row, regardless of whether you will use the row or not. If this is a datetime column, you will get better results with a half-open range comparison (ie: don't use BETWEEN) for the day after the end of the range, like this: op.OperationDate >= '20240401' AND op.OperationDate < '20240501' Also note the date literal format, which for historical reasons is correct for SQL Server for date-only values in ways the common yyyy-MM-dd format is not correct.

Time consumed is propably due to the client, because conumming 300 000 row into a graphical interface take long time to compute. Let see if there is some ASYNC_NETWORK_IO:
--1 create your temporary table as global :
SELECT 
    op.OperationId,
    op.OperationTypeId,
    op.BranchId,
    op.DateUpdated,
    op.OperationDate,
    op.StepCountTypeId,
    op.UserId,
    op.StatusTypeId,
    op.ChannelTypeId,
    cash.Amount, cash.OperationPersonId, cash.CurrencyTypeId
INTO ##Operation
FROM CashDesk.Cash.Operation op
LEFT JOIN CashDesk.Cash.CashOperation AS cash WITH (NOLOCK) ON op.OperationId=cash.OperationId
WHERE CAST(op.OperationDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '2024-04-01' AND '2024-04-30'
AND op.OperationTypeId IN (9, 11, 10, 13, 14, 15, 348, 369, 385, 432);

--2 open a new query window and type your extract query :
SELECT * FROM ##Operation;

--3 In the same window, now execute this query :
SELECT * 
FROM   sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats 
WHERE  session_id = @@SPID AND wait_time_ms > 0 
ORDER  BY wait_time_ms DESC

The row that shows "ASYNC_NETWORK_IO" indicate that SQL Server was waiting the client program that is not able to absorb immediatly all the data...
So you will see that this is not SQL Server that is slow, but the network or the client pragram (even if it is SSMS). It is not usaul to display 300 000 row of data, because usually, users may spend about 3 days without sleeping to view all those records on the screen !

One improvement is the Cast(OperationDate As Date) expression, because this must be computed for every row, regardless of whether you will use the row or not.
If this is a datetime column, you will get better results with a half-open range comparison (ie: don't use BETWEEN, which is always full open) with an exclusive upper bound for the day after the end of the range, like this: op.OperationDate >= '20240401' AND op.OperationDate < '20240501'
This avoids needing any computation work on the OperationDate values, which again would need to be done for every row. It also preserves the ability to use an index with the column for this query, which the cast() operation breaks. This can be huge, as indexing cuts to the core of database performance, but it's less likely to be an issue in a temp table. Also note the adjusted date literal format, which for historical reasons is correct for SQL Server for date-only values in ways the common yyyy-MM-dd format is not correct.
If this is a string column (varchar, nvarchar, etc), you should fix that, because a schema that uses a string type with a column with Date in the name really is broken.
But all of that is for the INSERT part of the issue, which is already fast. For the poor SELECT performance, I challenge the premise. There's no indication in this question the temp table is actually needed, and in my experience more than 90% of temp tables I encounter in the wild should not have been used in the first place.
